# Debug PySpark in Visual Studio Code

Tags: apache-spark, visual-studio-code, pyspark, pycharm

I am trying to find a way to debug PySpark codes in Visual Studio Code. I normally execute PySpark codes through the command spark-submit, and wonder if there is a way to debug it similar to when we debug normal Python codes (eg. add breakpoint and inspect param values). I understand that Spark normally creates graphs (or execution plans) prior to eventually trigger codes, which could potentially makes impossible to debug or troubleshoot during the runtime. However, I came across how I can debug in PyCharm (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/big-data-tools-spark-submit.html), and wanted to confirm with everyone.